# How to manually configure/create the ContextLoaderListener in Spring boot Web app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hope I am making sense... my understanding is that there are `DispatcherServlet` and `ContextLoaderListener`, and `DispatcherServlet` creates servlet application context. And `ContextLoaderListener` creates *root* application context, which belongs to the whole application (kind of a global thing). The idea is to put "web beans" in servlet context and "non-web beans" in root application context.

Now, my questions are:

1. is this root application context created no matter what? In other words, do I always get this root application context and servlet context, even I am not creating the root context explicitly? For example, if I use the simplest way to start the app,

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class MyApplication { 
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
       }
   }
   ```

does Spring boot framework still create the root context?

2. If I want to manually control/configure `ContextLoaderListener`, for example,

   ```
   public class MyContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener { ... }
   ```

how can I accomplish that ***without*** using any `web.xml` configuration (use Java config only)?

Having been search on the Web, but still could not put a whole picture together.

Many thanks.